# Blank page when parsing a number from HTML code Using 'PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser'

Tags: dom, curl, domparser

I'm using  [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net) And I have some HTML codes that from it i want to extract the first number appear, in this example is '`735438`':

```
<!-- Some Tds without onclick atribute ->
<td onclick="StatsAnnonce ('735438');" style="CURSOR:pointer;"  onmouseover="return escape('<img  src=/images/icon_stats.gif border=0 width=13 height=14> <b>Statistiques de cette annonce</b><li>Affichages des détails annonce</li><li>Classement par mois et par pays.</li>');">&nbsp;&nbsp;<img  src="/images/icon_stats.gif" border="0" width="13" height="14" alt="Statistique annonce">&nbsp;Stats&nbsp;</td>
<td onclick="ModifAnnonce ('735438','1','302528');" style="CURSOR:pointer;"  onmouseover="return escape('<img  src=/images/button_edit.gif border=0 width=13 height=14> <b>Editer cette annonce</b><li>Modifier : titre, texte, prix</li><li>Ajouter/Supprimer des photos</li>');">&nbsp;&nbsp;<img  src="/images/button_edit.gif" border="0" width="13" height="14" alt="Modifier l'annonce">&nbsp;Modif&nbsp;</td>
<td onclick="ProlongerAnnonce ('735438');" style="CURSOR:pointer;"  onmouseover="return escape('<img  src=/images/button_calendar.gif border=0 width=14 height=14> <b>Renouveler cette annonce</b>');"><img  src="/images/button_calendar.gif" border="0" width="14" height="14" alt="Renouveler l'annonce">&nbsp;Renouv&nbsp;</td>
<td onclick="DeleteAnnonce('735438','06/08/2012 00:50','302528','Bon appart s+1');" style="CURSOR:pointer;"  onmouseover="return escape('<img  src=/images/button_trash.gif border=0 width=13 height=14> <b>Supprimer cette annonce</b>');"><img  src="/images/button_trash.gif" border="0" width="13" height="14" alt="Supprimer l'annonce">&nbsp;Suppr&nbsp;</td>
```

I have tried with this code(according to the doc instructions) but not working :

```
$html = str_get_html('page.html');

// Find all <td> with the 'onclick' as attribute
$ret = $html->find('td[onclick]');


// Find just all <td>
$ret = $html->find('td');


foreach($ret as $val)
{
echo $val."<br/>";
}
```

The result is just a blank page with no code...
I'm newer too HTML DOM Parser, please if somewone have worked with this library help me...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd make sure that you're actually reading in the document (I'm pretty sure you're not at this point).  You should be using:

```
$html = file_get_html('page.html');  // This!
//$html = str_get_html('page.html'); // Not this!
```

Assuming you're trying to extract information from the `onclick` attribute, it seems you should use this in your `foreach` loop:

```
echo $val->onclick . "<br/>";  // This!
//echo $val."<br/>";  //Not this!
```

`$val` is still an html element at this point - I'm not sure what you'll get if you echo it out, but I'm guessing it's not what you're looking for.